# Проблема с перегрузкой оператора "<<" для файла

Tags: c++

Ошибка в след. коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "My2DArray.h"

...

ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, const My2DArray& matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.size; j++)
        {
            ofs << matrix.array_2d[i][j] << '\t'; // матрица типа double
        }
    }
    return ofs;

}
```

Ругается на "<<", т.к.: "существует несколько операторов, соответствующих этим операндам:            функцию (объявлено в строке 274 (в мной созданном файле)); функцию (объявлено в строке 404 из)            типы операндов: std::ofstream << double".

Что с этим делать?
Спасибо большое!

Comment: В том, что существует несколько операторов, соответствующих этим операндам...

Comment: Хорошо, что с этим делать?

Comment: `типы операндов: std::ofstream << double` выглядит как-то странно... Вы не делали перегрузок наподобие `ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, double val)`? Вообще приведённого кода не достаточно для ответа на вопрос. `объявлено в строке 404` Предлагаете _угадать_ чего вы там написали в 404 строке?

Comment: Нужен [mcve] - короткий кусок кода, который мы можем засунуть в компилятор и увидеть ту же ошибку, что и вы.

Comment: Посмотреть, откуда у вас два оператора. Что-то вы лишнее написали, или неверно вставили в заголовочный файл, или еще что... Кода-то — минимального воспроизводимого — нет. Можно нарваться на ситуацию звонка врачу "я тут хромаю, что делать", но его мази для суставов не помогут, потому что он же не видит, что вы пилой полступни отрезали...